# Create folder and subfolder with .txt imput file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch to create folders and subfolders using two .txt files

On file 'folder.txt' are my projects names eg. 'project 01' 'project 02' etc.
On file 'subfolder.txt' i need to create the estruture eg. 'WP' 'Discovery' 'Evidence' inside each project folder.

Some like this:

\project 01\WP

\project 01\Discovery

\project 01\Evidence

I tried some codes, but all i get is the first folder.txt directories, or all the folders in both txt files, making a bunch of messed folders

```
SET "destdir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\batch script"
FOR /f %%a in (folder.txt) DO (
md "%%a"
)
FOR /f %%b in (subfolder.txt) in (
'dir /b /a "%destdir%" ' ) DO (
md "%destdir%\%%b"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is just nest your `FOR` loop:

```
SET "destdir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\batch script"
FOR /f %%a in (folder.txt) DO (
    md "%destdir%\%%a"
    FOR /f %%b in (subfolder.txt) DO md "%destdir%\%%a\%%b"
)
```

In the above, the `subfolder.txt` listing is created for each instance of `folder.txt` (your projects). In other words, each entry in `folder.txt` iterates and creates the subfolder structure within the nested `FOR` loop (`%%b` variable).

Comment: thanks for the simple solution! But now i have a new problem, i used win7 and in my .txt files i put the folder with spaces in simples quotes. ex: 'folder 01' 'folder 02'. Now i'm in win8, and when i run the batch script the folder are not created. I tried put the names in simple and normal quotes and don't worked for me.